# Call nested Serializer's .update() method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a `JSONField` in my model that stores some configuration data. I want to access this field (both read and write) with ability to make partial updates of inner fields and their values.

For purpose of example let a model be called `MyModel` with `JSONField` called `config`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    config = JSONField(default=dict())
    ...
```

I created a separate `ViewSet` to access information stored in `config` field. Assume that `user` model has `ForeignKey` relation to `MyModel`. Simplified version of this `ViewSet` is:

```
class ConfigurationFieldViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

serializer_class = MyModelConfigurationSerializer

def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user.my_model
```

Data stored in `config` has a certain structure with several possible inner objects:

```
{
    "C1": {"counter": 42, "active": false},
    "C2": {"counter": 13, "active": true}
}
```

To access and correctly serialize `MyModel` instance at all levels of nesting I have created serializers for each level of field. To acces `config` field in `MyModel` itself I'm using this serializer:

```
class MyModelConfigurationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    configuration = ConfigurationFieldSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('configuration',)
```

To access and serialize first layer of `configuration` field there's second serializer:

```
class ConfigurationFieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    C1 = BaseConfigurationSerializer(required=True)
    C2 = BaseConfigurationSerializer(required=True)
```

At last to access inner structure of each `C1` and `C2` fields there's third serializer:

```
class BaseConfigurationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    counter = serializers.IntegerField(
        required=False,
        help_text=_('Some integer field help text')
    )
    active = serializers.BooleanField(
        required=False,
        help_text=_('Some boolean field description')
    )
```

The code above works perfectly to read data stored in `config` field and correctly serializes it's inner objects. The problem appears when I try to perform a `PUT` on this field.

If I override `update` method at the level of `MyModelConfigurationSerializer`, then serializers verify data I'm submitting but as a chunk and I'm only able to save it all at once. If I'm trying to submit some inner field I still correctly receive validation errors by inner serializers.

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.configuration = validated_data.get(
            'configuration', instance.configuration
        )
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

What I'm unable to do though is call `update` methods of inner serializers (`ConfigurationFieldSerializer` and `BaseConfigurationSerializer` in this case): if I implement their `update` methods they simply do not get called.

According to [DRF Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) writable nested representations are possible and corresponding `update` or `create` methods should be called whenever `update` is called on serializer of top level.

Comment: I believe you need to trigger a partial update by using the `PATCH` method instead of `PUT`

Comment: @ivissani The same effect, only 1 level serializer's `update` is called

Comment: Sure, DRF does not handle creation or update of nested serializers by itself, you need to write custom `create()` and `update()` methods if you want to do so. I was commenting on the validation.

Comment: @ivissani but even if I write those methods they are not called

Comment: You need to write a custom `update()` method in your top-level serializer that handles the update of nested objects.

Comment: @ivissani this is exactly what I described in the question and what I was able to come up with so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191918/discussion-between-ivissani-and-stan-redoute).

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem recently as well, and it looks like the way you are doing it is the "only way" when it comes to nested writable serializers.

From the [same DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-update-methods-for-nested-representations) you've probably already seen:

> Because the behavior of nested creates and updates can be ambiguous, and may require complex dependencies between related models, REST framework 3 requires you to always write these methods explicitly. **The default ModelSerializer .create() and .update() methods do not include support for writable nested representations.**
>
> There are however, third-party packages available such as DRF Writable Nested that support automatic writable nested representations.

Basically it means that when you have nesting it won't even try to call any of the nested serializer storage methods.

That may seem like a bit of a pain, but in retrospect it's probably better for the design of your application. Your example is pretty simple, but in other situations the ordering in which things are saved might be important. If `update` of each nested serializer was ran automatically then DRF would have to somehow know when to save each thing.

As an example, if your example was about `create` rather than `update`, it would mean that you need to first store your model `MyModel` before storing the configuration on top of it. However DRF cannot know that.

Also it could as easily have been that configuration was actually another related model which needed to be saved **first** before you could save a relation to it from `MyModel`. So DRF takes the route of just telling you to do it yourself, at the root serializer.

From my own experience this is also helpful to allow you to fine-tune performance later (ex. in your case you can avoid saving `MyModel` twice).

Finally, if you want to make your code more modular, you can still do it (send segments of the validated data to different handlers, eg to a new `update_configurations()` function), it just won't be done automatically using the nested serializers.

Comment: Thanks, those are all helpfull notes. I'm a little dissapointed that it's impossible to do it nice-and-easy because my API generates automatic swagger documentation for each URI and I was hoping by doing it with nested representations I'll be able to provide a swagger-dummy for developers working on client-side of the app

Comment: There is still value in using nested serializers, just the schema definition and validation is already a win. We are also using swagger and have plenty of nested serializers that don't handle their own storage. In the long run it doesn't feel less easy/elegant.